Can Ethereum full node be used to get all token transfers from the past?
I need to get all ERC-20 tokens transfers from 2020 till current last block. I am considering using ethereum etl python module for this. Thus I need to start a local Ethereum node. I have hardware resourses for a full node but not an archive node.  The docs state that:

Only the most recent 128 block states are stored in a full node - older block states are pruned periodically and represented as a series of checkpoints from which any previous state can be regenerated on request.

So my question is, does this mean that Etereum full node, non archive one will be suitable for my goal and I will be able to get transfers data past most recent 128 blocks?

Ethereum full node, with the full “receipts” (event logs) history (this is configurable), allows you to get all historical ERC-20 Transfer events.
No archive node needed.

Thanks for the response!
Does this also mean that a snap node with all receipts will also work for my task? Also in geth docs in Command-line Options I can't find receipts history parameter, can you please clarify what is it called? Will highly appreciate your help!

As long as you have 100% receipts you can get transfers.
More here:
https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/ethereum-blockchain-docker-compose/blob/e65b01a25e172c666275dd118740a9a2f3b571b4/ethereum/docker-compose.yml#L34
